# Cannot generate cloud backend in android studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

I am trying to generate a cloud backend using the "google cloud tool" in android studio, however it gives the following errors:

```
Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.0:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) on project MyApplication-AppEngine: Execution default of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.0:endpoints_get_discovery_doc failed: A required class was missing while executing com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.0:endpoints_get_discovery_doc: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
```

I have installed maven 3.1.1 and android studio is version 0.3.1 (both of which is the newest version as of october 24th)

I seems that the error has been fixed in the appengine-maven-plugin version 1.8.3, but i simply cannot seem to force android studio to use that version.

How do I setup maven/android studio/google app engine, so that it can autogenerate the backend?

Thanks in advance!

PS: i have google this for 2 days now, and have gotten nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the templates in the cloud tools plugin use 1.8.0, these are not changeable.  The problem as you have noticed is an incompatibility with Maven 3.1.1. If it is possible, you might try using maven 3.0.4/3.0.5 instead of 3.1.1 which are known to work with the plugin.  The template is undergoing changes right now to address a couple of things (including the issue you are having), it will be updated in the future.

Comment: Ok, thought as much... Do you know when that would happen by the way?

Comment: Unfortunately all I can say is that it's in the pipeline, I'm not sure what the allocation/priority of resources are.  However you might try the helloendpoints sample on github.  Those are more up to date (although I have not personally played with them).

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-android