# GoogleAppEngine backend generation with Android Studio fails due to Maven installation

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

I am trying to generate a Google cloud backend with Android studio.

I have been following the basic google tutorial, however the error when I click the "generate cloud backend" button is "Could not find a valid installation of maven. Perhaps you have not installed Maven or have not setup your Maven paths".

I have maven set up in my path:
M2_HOME /Users/seren/apache-maven-3.1.1

I have tried a different version of maven as well ([also suggested on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585598/cannot-generate-cloud-backend-in-android-studio)) apache-maven-3.0.5, but this did not work.

Has anyone managed to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: did you add it in the path?

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way round...? M2_HOME\bin?

Comment: I'm on mac, seems fine to me, I can call mvn from commandline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following:

1. If you are able to do a `mvn` from command line, then maven is installed and is available in the PATH.
2. Ensure that `M2_HOME` environment variable is indeed pointing to the root of your maven directory.
3. In the Project Settings, go to Maven. Ensure that the Maven path is not overwriten and then the entry is empty with the instruction saying that M2_HOME will be used.
4. Do restart your Android Studio, just in case you did these settings while it was open.

Comment: I've tried all these things, and even re-created the project from scratch.  M2_HOME points to Users/seren/apache-maven-3.0.5 which is my maven root directory. M2_HOME is the default used in the settings in android studio.

Comment: I have Apache Maven 3.0.4. I am on a Windows machine but hopefully that should not matter. Worse case scenario - would Eclipse work for you, the tooling seems more stable there.

Comment: I tried 3.0.4, no joy, looks like I will have to wait for an update or try Eclipse.  Thanks